# Core-Data: Cases in which a XML-Database can be corrupted

Tags: core-data

I got an error from core-data that a value "" could not be parsed.
This value belonged to a non optional entity attribute of type **double** with 0 as default.

What can cause such data corruption?

Comment: Here is another example: **<EntTask: 0x100647aa0> (entity: EntTask; id: 0x101a3df80 <x-coredata://83220494-271F-4BEF-9A09-9948C49A4C94/EntTask/p103> ; data: <fault>)**

Comment: The data-fault from above is repairable by accessing all relation(sets) from the entity. Example: **NSSet* children = entity.children.** The **magic** is probably done by access-observers which load the necessary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to your question "what could cause such data corruption" is "faulting".

Core data will only fetch the attributes when it needs them. This is a feature, not a bug, as it helps manage memory and performance efficiently behind the scenes. However, if you use a construct returned by a core data fetch (such as an array with fetch results) and construct an XLM it is conceivable that the faults are not filled (i.e., Core Data does not go to the persistent store to fetch the faulted data automatically).

Your observation that everything is there once you explicitly call the relationship like in `children = entity.children` corroborates this thesis.

So -no, not access observers, but faulting is responsible for your data loss.

Comment: Yes, faulting is one possibility. But what happened to the double attribute? In XML, numbers are represented as strings(The local DOCTYPE of Core-Data defines it as **ISO 8601** ). So "0" was rewritten to "". What can cause that?

Comment: Fault could lead to there being no data, not 0.